# Нужно решить задачу с использованием объединения таблиц (JOIN)

Tags: mysql, sql

1. Пусть задан некоторый пользователь.

Из всех друзей этого пользователя найдите человека, который больше всех общался с нашим пользователем.

Это решение указанной задачи:

```
SELECT
    from_user_id, 
    (select concat(firstname,'', lastname) from users where id = messages.from_user_id) as name,
    COUNT(*) as send
FROM messages 
where to_user_id = 1 
AND from_user_id IN (
     select initiator_user_id from friend_requests 
     WHERE (target_user_id = 1) and status ='approved'
     UNION
     select target_user_id from friend_requests 
     WHERE (initiator_user_id = 1) and status ='approved' 
)
GROUP BY from_user_id
ORDER BY send desc 
limit 6;
```

Необходимо решить указанную задачу, но уже с использованием объединения таблиц (`JOIN`)

Я попытaлся ее решить, но есть неточности. Прошу помочь

```
SELECT
    from_user_id, 
    (messages.from_user_id = concat(firstname,'', lastname) from users where id) as name,
    COUNT(*) as send
FROM messages
JOIN friend_requests ON to_user_id = target_user_id and from_user_id = initiator_user_id and status ='approved'
GROUP BY from_user_id
ORDER BY send desc 
limit 4;
```

Comment: Как минимум без структуры `CREATE TABLE` не помочь в данном вопросе. Выложите её и `INSERT INTO`

Answer (score 0):

Я попытaлся ее решить, но есть неточности. Прошу помочь

```
SELECT
    from_user_id, 
    (messages.from_user_id = concat(firstname,'', lastname) from users where id) as name,
    COUNT(*) as send
FROM messages
JOIN friend_requests ON to_user_id = target_user_id and from_user_id = initiator_user_id and status ='approved'
GROUP BY from_user_id
ORDER BY send desc 
limit 4;
```

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. а этот «ответ» пожалуйста удалите.

Comment: Вам надо дополнить вопрос нажав [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1344114/edit), а не давать ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
    m.from_user_id, 
    (select concat(firstname,'', lastname) from users u where u.id = m.from_user_id) as name,
    COUNT(*) as send
FROM messages m
JOIN friend_requests fr
 ON (fr.status ='approved' AND
     (fr.initiator_user_id = m.to_user_id AND fr.target_user_id = m.from_user_id
      OR fr.target_user_id = m.to_user_id AND fr.initiator_user_id = m.from_user_id))
where m.to_user_id = 1 
GROUP BY m.from_user_id
ORDER BY send desc 
limit 6;
```